# How to get the filter of all orders due of the current month?

Tags: sql-server

I have my daily totals to get the sum of all orders which is filtered by the `EntryDate`.

Now, I want to have it as a basis for me to filter the `DueDate` instead of `EntryDate`  for the `CurrentMonth`.

How to do that?

How would I edit the `WHERE` clause?

My current code now is:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date, 'Sales Orders' AS Type, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Qty, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2),0)) AS [Total Ex GST]
FROM    dbo.SalesOrder
WHERE   (DateCreated > CONVERT(int, GETDATE() - 0.5))
```

Comment: and this code actually works?

Comment: yes of course. It's running and working fine. @Harry

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select
  dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)   AS [1st Day of Current Month]
, dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,0) AS [1st Day of Next Month]
```

so your  where clause for "*DueDate instead...for the current month*" might look like this:

```
where DueDate >= dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)
  and DueDate  < dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,0)
```

What these functions do is:

- calculate the number of months from the current date/time from zero (which is the base date of 1900-01-01 in SQL Server)
- then add the number of months to zero (i.e. 1900-01-01) to calculate first day of the current month, and
- add 1 to the number of months and this calculates the first day of the next month

Answer (score 0):

I have amended the code and it works fine:

```
SELECT dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) AS [1st Day of Current Month]
  , 'Sales Orders' AS Type
  , COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Qty
  , '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2), 0)) AS [Total Ex GST]
FROM dbo.SalesOrder
WHERE DueDate >= dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)
AND DueDate  < dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,0)
```

[image]